# Retrieving phone numbers from a VBA HTTP query to Google Maps

Tags: excel, google-maps, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA macro that would cycle through a list of city names, look up "City hall + city name" in Google Maps, and get the city hall's phone number.

I stitched together the following code:

```
    Public Sub toGoogleMaps()


Dim xmlhttp As Object
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
Dim googleKey As String
googleKey = "XXXXXXXX" ' my API key here

'query
xmlhttp.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?" & _
        "query=laon+mairie&key=" & googleKey, False ' "mairie" means city hall, Laon is a city in France
xmlhttp.send

'result
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = (xmlhttp.responseText)

End Sub
```

This gets me the following results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaceSearchResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <name>Ville de Laon</name>
  <type>city_hall</type>
  <type>local_government_office</type>
  <type>point_of_interest</type>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <formatted_address>Place du Général Leclerc, 02000 Laon, France</formatted_address>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>49.5650667</lat>
    <lng>3.6205478</lng>
   </location>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>49.5636950</lat>
     <lng>3.6193978</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>49.5663947</lat>
     <lng>3.6220975</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
  <rating>4.2</rating>
  <icon>https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/civic_building-71.png</icon>
  <reference>CmRbAAAAtOpLATTyHjGzjZ7imiwNmiWnCqeXd1JdTwzvEx6qBgk0iY2g7D7Z7bTo6N4XsXiRKzScnAomiwaLs1m3HdcBYb9u_RaTqb1EJ5U3hIFDZ2E5AO5Gp1AKmvj3yVtz09TuEhD3uLKLr7MGvZ9bWm4h_TviGhQF9Nv9tJY5hLpTm04H6L2yiTJ9SQ</reference>
  <id>ee7eb46a2d124d7e6db9c0ea688f734ffc5ddecf</id>
  <opening_hours>
   <open_now>true</open_now>
  </opening_hours>
  <photo>
   <photo_reference>CmRaAAAALrOf00J_nfKw5DUQS_Xa2RZLcIUNPubp4y1K1_4lneepMVabaGO8WBZqXdJTigSS4dlUgnFhj1BBNyvyeqVicquXiCWDrsT2Iq2lo-FS2qZ9VKZzg6KxrYF7S1UMHMU4EhA980LRWeEkeSO3YAFa2p4vGhSMvwkhIuU9FH3uOF5SIF8T4r_Ysg</photo_reference>
   <width>992</width>
   <height>720</height>
   <html_attribution>&lt;a href=&quot;https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117709460583068449109/photos&quot;&gt;Pierre Bastien&lt;/a&gt;</html_attribution>
  </photo>
  <place_id>ChIJGd9IgrO06UcR2vGqCWkMLtk</place_id>
 </result>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

As you can see, it's missing the "phone number" field, although manually searching for "Laon Mairie" in Google Maps will get you the phone number.

How can I retrieve my query's phone number?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a phone number you will need an additional request for [place details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details). Please note that places search doesn't return all fields for places. You should get a place ID from the places text search response `ChIJGd9IgrO06UcR2vGqCWkMLtk` and execute place details query

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJGd9IgrO06UcR2vGqCWkMLtk&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

This will provide a detailed information that includes phone numbers as `formatted_phone_number` and `international_phone_number` fields

```
{
  "html_attributions":[

  ],
  "result":{
    "address_components":[
      {
    "long_name":"Place du Général Leclerc",
    "short_name":"Place du Général Leclerc",
    "types":[
      "route"
    ]
      },
      {
    "long_name":"Laon",
    "short_name":"Laon",
    "types":[
      "locality","political"
    ]
      },
      {
    "long_name":"Aisne",
    "short_name":"Aisne",
    "types":[
      "administrative_area_level_2","political"
    ]
      },
      {
    "long_name":"Hauts-de-France",
    "short_name":"Hauts-de-France",
    "types":[
      "administrative_area_level_1","political"
    ]
      },
      {
    "long_name":"France",
    "short_name":"FR",
    "types":[
      "country","political"
    ]
      },
      {
    "long_name":"02000",
    "short_name":"02000",
    "types":[
      "postal_code"
    ]
      }
    ],
    "adr_address":"Place du Général Leclerc, 02000 Laon, France",
    "formatted_address":"Place du Général Leclerc, 02000 Laon, France",
    "formatted_phone_number":"03 23 22 30 30",
    "geometry":{
      "location":{
    "lat":49.5650667,"lng":3.6205478
      },
      "viewport":{
    "northeast":{
      "lat":49.56639383029149,"lng":3.622096630291502
    },
    "southwest":{
      "lat":49.5636958697085,"lng":3.619398669708497
    }
      }
    },
    "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/civic_building-71.png",
    "id":"ee7eb46a2d124d7e6db9c0ea688f734ffc5ddecf",
    "international_phone_number":"+33 3 23 22 30 30",
    "name":"Laon Mayor",
    "opening_hours":{
      "open_now":true,
      "periods":[
    {
      "close":{
        "day":1,
        "time":"1230"
      },
      "open":{
        "day":1,
        "time":"0830"
      }
    },
    {
      "close":{
        "day":1,
        "time":"1700"
      },
      "open":{
        "day":1,
        "time":"1330"
      }
    },
    {
      "close":{
        "day":2,
        "time":"1230"
      },
      "open":{
        "day":2,
        "time":"0830"
      }
    },
    {
      "close":{
        "day":2,
        "time":"1700"
      },
      "open":{
        "day":2,
        "time":"1330"
      }
    },
    {
      "close":{
        "day":3,
        "time":"1230"
      },
      "open":{
        "day":3,
        "time":"0830"
      }
    },
    {
      "close":{
        "day":3,
        "time":"1700"
      },
      "open":{
        "day":3,
        "time":"1330"
      }
    },
    {
      "close":{
        "day":4,
        "time":"1230"
      },
      "open":{
        "day":4,
        "time":"0830"
      }
    },
    {
      "close":{
        "day":4,
        "time":"1700"
      },
      "open":{
        "day":4,
        "time":"1330"
      }
    },
    {
      "close":{
        "day":5,
        "time":"1230"
      },
      "open":{
        "day":5,
        "time":"0830"
      }
    },
    {
      "close":{
        "day":5,
        "time":"1630"
      },
      "open":{
        "day":5,
        "time":"1330"
      }
    }
      ],
      "weekday_text":[
    "Monday: 8:30 AM – 12:30 PM, 1:30 – 5:00 PM","Tuesday: 8:30 AM – 12:30 PM, 1:30 – 5:00 PM","Wednesday: 8:30 AM – 12:30 PM, 1:30 – 5:00 PM","Thursday: 8:30 AM – 12:30 PM, 1:30 – 5:00 PM","Friday: 8:30 AM – 12:30 PM, 1:30 – 4:30 PM","Saturday: Closed","Sunday: Closed"
      ]
    },
    "photos":[
      {
    "height":720,
    "html_attributions":[
      "Pierre Bastien"
    ],
    "photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAKX8T5aJUO5579J0ZWTLLRduE4XLFFtU1-tSaHlcBxEMWpSmYcJR0Qz2rUPN304D8s3J0q6r0wZ_R8TKv3PeVj-2r6eeHGrYzpCAjKaru5cJ9g9UuSR2H-SM38LmIyg72EhAkWTMx-u-HaaYQaENSA9hqGhRfX2UPgBTn-7FBTJ_WxfQUa4SZrg",
    "width":992
      },
      {
    "height":1181,
    "html_attributions":[
      "Bernard Pietrzykowski"
    ],
    "photo_reference":"CmRaAAAA5JdnQU5XYyk2SJVsTyAlFvZ5MFMeOwNul7VfO1tmJypwxj0-flEqjI4BcbWNy40u2gEekv9vMAk3f1kw0Y5RE09fO8WSnPnOESF-CySYq5pFb-iKEdXEVxli30zZrNw7EhCT_kXTmsXAmN-O0oacZyN3GhQxL2rCe9ylgFZFl2AJPqKGtjJevQ",
    "width":1772
      },
      {
    "height":1536,
    "html_attributions":[
      "Philippe Gault"
    ],
    "photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAIAOtiu-Y4pbFZh40uZZ790wvQ0LYjXPd8P9M1b_pQZH_sgXu3r55Xwm1Wjh6a5dFP7KYg4idvCAbtbppSvGdVMlzlaDKD9eBABHEAWtULXWt681mA6m_kG5ZuxSQ0TtDEhAL9bpkFFkgIkDMFMsSnKX6GhRCisteb4quO0DG3rdjmcZosrTg1w",
    "width":2048
      },
      {
    "height":1181,
    "html_attributions":[
      "Bernard Pietrzykowski"
    ],
    "photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAjntS3AwPepXfY8q5RsJY_jiEfoLHNbTWu7kjoQti1g92vTHEqgvxpmHucgQPzI9GZaJ_9V_srF-WGynID5g-AZJ3gCiJ3ENHvCKG2lrfqIixg4JXl1vHX8ze71KJRXD6EhCHw4CV0in4IbHun5MFLC_KGhSyJuMkFe1YbvUA5yTO3zmno0lvDw",
    "width":1772
      },
      {
    "height":1181,
    "html_attributions":[
      "Bernard Pietrzykowski"
    ],
    "photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAZwaWIY0Y1v-3_VI4rNaJ-yPHJ6p6aA7hHlp0_jee8syXLfWt2K0eOaj0kTII29tnpQvmfryo2kXK-x8bshPX-9IrCZaqzyLq8DkV5ISpZRsGHpoyL_ECBktK4kEV0SFaEhBYiPY9ZeuWoe_jKkI-bKO1GhTueIqjIp0IaJBIXKnxHJJ-A-xVQg",
    "width":1772
      },
      {
    "height":1772,
    "html_attributions":[
      "Bernard Pietrzykowski"
    ],
    "photo_reference":"CmRaAAAA51UZMLQa6YVToNO-hTRqmmEBdCm0hYGtQFfDfeonA8DSIc6koCs_FCWiVoBVNOWU2Wl3a5fK_tyB4NwpUo2dwHpgwEyZcmQPyKijPQjAfhc2sj_qlJy6bAfbdPQYWLE6EhDZpSa3XGESfx1iyl1p0VUvGhTkHnnKfo_Wt1IWHyHBBcEX6uy_1Q",
    "width":1181
      },
      {
    "height":1181,
    "html_attributions":[
      "Bernard Pietrzykowski"
    ],
    "photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAuTO3ki8_JdQkHYw6yRNExEI9FqMLJcacF35LwWRoqnvVqqMQ06l-IKRHFu2OeBG3N2MfHFcGPdaEwN9pr5otJaqLq2Pankge0_xX9mgUdguNUBjovwTl35Op1FIr8-qpEhAaT6Jr90Km_Bc60txENaiIGhTxxccIt1r-vdi6XeBepquTpxxthA",
    "width":1772
      },
      {
    "height":2432,
    "html_attributions":[
      "Umberto d'Agnone"
    ],
    "photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAwSDQ6mkqf5yrX7NgVLX8YxJT9YUcYGy23NfZojMjNjuMYOIyhVaohvmRtEHvfo32gtaT0ggC-xPfUBnGEbWABAWhLKv6UrNsbRDjD8lvRhhZHOwHU0I9_EfC08yyjONPEhBSUhT9bNHY_HbxQVr5W3UYGhTnCfPI5o6M0xGAzCkhHCARBpEahA",
    "width":3244
      },
      {
    "height":1772,
    "html_attributions":[
      "Bernard Pietrzykowski"
    ],
    "photo_reference":"CmRaAAAARa1T2SFWJcEaOHRTUxfSi7l72zMNtqGYQ4R6qkfFUUHmD7qbVHeuCEhuq79Z9wXrklbRcohwmZpjPosOt_AFiwn9HoW8pmcR1R7FohO52aIh1Ue1LRwXsuhFjLhdzSSeEhCo-_L4zkQMZjRt_EQN-idqGhRCbZ_ipOUZKyReCjmA9g549k4Ypw",
    "width":1181
      },
      {
    "height":1193,
    "html_attributions":[
      "Philippe Gault"
    ],
    "photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAYqrqxv1vtGMziEFeU1DSlYCmR2oMlNbWjuDsM8fDF6Z_JJjQuoUpPELvtVbnfoAhw-2YC8Jx-EdHlcq5xfH5dnrYcEYqQX5yEP6dExgUWJoO0HhL3n5PX680qDUCwC_pEhBj10VKpDOaPXAthtBJsHIsGhRzTsp17MiQpdYZ9RgkMQc9WrkXpw",
    "width":1913
      }
    ],
    "place_id":"ChIJGd9IgrO06UcR2vGqCWkMLtk",
    "rating":4.2,
    "reference":"CmRSAAAAOSqJyFp6k3Bpsnv210QbglGA98GhqUFeZLijoz68BOZIo72jTGyH4pkIhyW9wKcSMtsqlP0gw911lKt39X3U21GIhIyHhYxdCOdM0Nrv5PUTzUGXsoiVhoVAjnsD_xIgEhDTuqSWLLDur7vmA4WLI61mGhQ7pvgWnoQpDBhuXu_QIWxknugfAQ",
    "reviews":[
      {
    "author_name":"Jean de la tour",
    "author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/109488205605268400049/reviews",
    "language":"fr",
    "profile_photo_url":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-g0yCLclMvPg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADs/hKYhzXbWhwE/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba3/photo.jpg",
    "rating":3,"relative_time_description":"8 months ago",
    "text":"J'aime cette ville surtout la cité médiévales  .mais je trouve navrant de voir tomber en ruine la chapelle des templiers ,c'est notre histoire notre patrimoine  , je suis déçu de voir ça. Il Onts parlé de restauration sur les journaux il y a longtemps toujours rien n'est fait ? POURQUOI !...",
    "time":1501614076
      },
      {
    "author_name":"Leeloulouve",
    "author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/114615007607211047327/reviews",
    "language":"fr",
    "profile_photo_url":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-njdAtpErEg4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABf0/79pd6bK-3rU/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
    "rating":4,"relative_time_description":"a month ago",
    "text":"C'est une belle ville historique",
    "time":1520954743
      },
      {
    "author_name":"samir lemgueres",
    "author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/102661995701404304520/reviews",
    "language":"fr",
    "profile_photo_url":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-rTugSwRdJzo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAcvs/_HkiyHf1O5w/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba7/photo.jpg",
    "rating":5,"relative_time_description":"7 months ago",
    "text":"Acceuil excellent et rapidité pour les services.",
    "time":1505987381
      },
      {
    "author_name":"Françoise Dubois",
    "author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/101967328643607484206/reviews",
    "language":"fr",
    "profile_photo_url":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-CR9TqTPyttk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACLGyWA1GGLclILFViMUfxxW69E36GSZng/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
    "rating":4,"relative_time_description":"2 years ago",
    "text":"Scrabble  salle de la mairie",
    "time":1451139958
      },
      {
    "author_name":"Philippe Magot",
    "author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/101689226627223243247/reviews",
    "language":"fr",
    "profile_photo_url":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/--mH2dOha59A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAOc/rLgEMN2DqHk/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
    "rating":1,"relative_time_description":"a year ago",
    "text":"17h c'est pas 16h45 Ahhhh l'administration",
    "time":1467038661
      }
    ],
    "scope":"GOOGLE",
    "types":[
      "city_hall","local_government_office","point_of_interest","establishment"
    ],
    "url":"https://maps.google.com/?cid=15649459400432349658",
    "utc_offset":120,
    "vicinity":"Place du Général Leclerc, Laon",
    "website":"http://www.laon.fr/"
  },
  "status":"OK"
}
```

I hope this helps!